# 403 errors on .js and .css files on first load, solved on refresh

Tags: javascript, iis

I am hoping someone can help.

I have an issue with pages on my website returning 403 errors on some .js and .css files and images on the first load - visible in the Chrome inspect console. This causes the page to render improperly. Oddly, all the issues are resolved on a page refresh.
If I do a hard refresh, the problems reappear, if I do a normal refresh they are resolved.

I have put hours into this, but I think it may be an issue with the server/IIS, since the exact same page served from a different machine has no issues at all.

A test page on the live server that shows the errors is here: https://www.zygology.com/store/pc/web_test3.asp
The exact same page served on the test server and showing no errors is here: http://test2.zygology.com/store/pc/web_test3.asp

The actual homepage on which the errors are also visible is https://www.zygology.com and the test website showing no errors is http://test2.zygology.com

To see the issue, open the inspect console and see the 403 errors returned on the scripts that are trying to load. It happens on all browsers.

Both the live machine and the test machine are running Windows/IIS

I would be grateful for any help that can be offered.

Thanks

Comment: IIS version? windows version?

Comment: This should be a problem caused by permissions. Have you found that a 403 error appears in https? You need to give users full permissions.

Comment: @nadeem taj the windows version is 2019 and IIS 10.0.17763.1

Comment: @samwu Yes, it appears in https. Can you expand a bit what you mean here and what you could do to test/fix it. The issue only occurs on first load, after a refresh it is fine. Would that be the case if it was down to permissions?

Comment: This is good. What about Browser - Chrome version? and did you check with other browser, same behavior? . If you give a test on IE that will be great.

Comment: @nadeem Taj yes, it happens on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and all are running the latest up to date versions. Did you test the links in the original post yourself at all? I would be ok interested to know if you experience the problem.

Comment: You need to change permissions on the folder bootstrap/css/javascript. Your super user may be able to access it but it doesn't mean others have access to it, that's why you still need to change the permissions. IIS is very picky when it comes to permissions. Honestly, I didn't check the links.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, unfortunately none of these worked. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in IIS 8.5 when we moved to a new server.  The issue was that the IP Address and Domain Restrictions module had been installed on the new server and it was limiting concurrent requests to 5.  If you have that module installed, double click it and select "Edit Dynamic Restrictions" on the right menu.  In the resulting dialogue, make sure the 2 "Deny IP Address..." check boxes are cleared or that the settings are appropriate for the number of requests you expect to receive concurrently or over a period of time.

Comment: This solution work for me in IIS where I could access every JS and CSS files after set this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

"Solution" for me was to publish Debug version, not the Release version. I think it's due to a Bundle misconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

We have a customer with Plesk for Windows and I believe Deluxe hosting. We had the same problem for months, until I discovered that the MIME type for javascript was not an allowed MIME type.

I'm not sure about other configurations and control panels, if you're having Plesk, go to Website & Domains -> IIS Settings and just add "text/javascript .js" to MIME types. Recycle the applicaiton pool, or restart the application and refresh the browser using Hard Reload (Ctrl+F5 on most browsers)